# Extra horizontal spacing after & in align

Tags: spacing, align

Here is my input:

```
\begin{align}
&\text{HIn}_{(aq)} + \text{H$_2$O$_{(ℓ)}$} \rightleftharpoons \text{H$_3$O$^+_{(aq)}$} + &&\text{In$^-_{(aq)}$ $\kern 2pc$△H > O} 
\\
&\text{yellow} &&\text{purple}
\end{align}
```

Here is my output:

[image: Output]

Notice the gap between the '+' and the 'In' with 'purple' under it. How can I avoid this gap and have a single space instead?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is expected with `align`. With `alignat`, the space between alignment columns can be controlled. Could you please transform you code snippet into a complete example that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without any error? This is what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a package that ie dedicated to wirting chemical reactions such as the `chemformula` package?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've neglected to mention that this input i in a plugin field on a website we are building. My apologies for omitting that important info. As such, I'm not able to define classes or packages. This gives me limited control. I tried alignat, but this could not compile. The plugin appears to have limited interpreting.

Comment: Although you say you can't use packages, you are using `align`.  If this means that you have the facilities of `amsmath`, you could use `begin{aligned}[t]...` for the "purple" component without any `&&` preceding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, horizontal space between adjacent right-left pairs of columns is expected with `align` and `align*`, but can be tuned and even removed using `alignat`, `alignat*`, etc. These environments expect an argument, maybe this is why you didn't manage to make `alignat` work? The argument in question is the number of pairs of right-left aligned columns. Equivalently, count the maximum number of `&`s in a given row and call it *n*. The argument to give to `alignat` (or `alignat*`, etc.) is then (*n*+1)/2.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & \text{HIn}_{(aq)} + \text{H$_2$O$_{(\ell)}$} \rightleftharpoons
  \text{H$_3$O$^+_{(aq)}$} + && \text{In$^-_{(aq)}$ $\kern 2pc \Delta H > O$} \\
  & \text{yellow} && \text{purple}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! The argument for alignat was the key info I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of well-designed LaTeX packages specifically for typesetting chemical formulae.  I recommend that you use one of those.  I have made good experiences with `chemformula`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\[
    \ch{
        !(yellow)( HIn_{(aq)} ) + H2O_{($\ell$)} <=> H3O^+_{(aq)} + !(purple)( In^-_{(aq)} )
    }
    \quad \Delta H > O
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the states, you could also use `\aq{}` and `\lqd{}` that come with the `phases` module of `chemmacros`.

Comment: @leandriis You should post an additional answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke, thanks for this. You'll see from my comment on my question that I'm not able to use packages. My apologies for not including this info earlier.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Henri Menke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536873/134144), I have used `\aq{}` and `\lqd{}` from the `phases` module of `chemmacros`. For the enthalpy, I have used the `\state` command from the `thermodynamics` module of `chemmacros`. The reaction equation as well as the annotations below the reactant and product are done with the `\ce` command from `chemformula` (which itself is already loaded by the `phases` module of `chemmacros`, so no need for `\usepackage{chemformula}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={phases, thermodynamics}}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\ch{!(yellow)(HIn\aq{}) + H2O\lqd{} <=> H3O^{+}\aq{} + !(purple)(In$^{-}$\aq{})} \quad \state{H}> 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, that is useful to know.